# Docker Container DB dont show up

Tags: mysql, docker

Hello currently I get in touch with Docker. I am doing their getting started and I ran into a problem which I cant solve and I dont understand why it dont work. First of all I create a network using.

```
$ docker network create todo-app
```

After that, I set up a Container mysql database and connect it with the network with following code.

```
$  docker run -d \
 --network todo-app --network-alias mysql \
 -v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret \
 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos \
 mysql:5.7
```

I check for the Container id with

```
$ docker ps
```

After that I use the command to get into the mysql CLI ? (not sure on that yet)

$ docker exec -it  mysql -u root -p

After getting there I use

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
```

to show all DB on my PC? But there is non listed named todos and i dont know why it dont appear.

I would like to hear what you are thinking im struggeling a little there. Thanks for the replies. Sorry for my english skills.

Comment: i will link you the tutorial im doing https://docs.docker.com/get-started/07_multi_container/

Answer (score 0):

Run container in the foreground and check the logs.

Comment: Hey I just did that and it looks like it runs without any error but I cant tell for sure cause I never set one up before. But anyway here is the output of the run command without detaching it.  https://imgur.com/a/heqwnTe. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Following [Part 7: Multi-container apps](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/07_multi_container/), I ran into this exact issue just now.

Chances are, you have run that same command at least once.

```bash
# command to run as per the docs
docker run -d \
    --network todo-app --network-alias mysql \
    -v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos \
    mysql:5.7
```

And the first time you ran the command you unknowingly made a mistake. For me, I mistyped `MYSQL_DATABASE` FOR `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`. Yours might be different. In any case, it seems making small mistakes like this might have caused the `mysql:5.7` image to not be set up correctly with the `todos` database. (Not entirely sure.)

Adding to that, the first time you run that command, Docker creates a `todo-mysql-data` volume, which does not get overwritten when you run that same command again.

So as a "fix", you might have to delete the `todo-mysql-data` volume first.

```bash
docker volume rm todo-mysql-data
```

And then re-create the `todo-mysql-data` volume implicitly by re-running the image with the above command; this time without mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble it was my fault I guess cause I used the Command I pointed out above but I definetly had to use this command :

```
 docker run -d \
 --network todo-app --network-alias mysql \
 --platform "linux/amd64" \
 -v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret \
 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos \
 mysql:5.7
```

Because im using Linux... Such a dumb mistake but i swear this wasnt there two months ago when I asked this Qeustion.